# Laravel : Redis No connection could be made : [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I have installed redis with laravel by adding `"predis/predis":"~1.0"`,

Then for testing i added the following code :

```
public function showRedis($id = 1)
   {
      $user = Redis::get('user:profile:'.$id);
      Xdd($user);
   }
```

In app/config/database.php i have :

```
'redis' => [
        'cluster' => false,
        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],
```

It throws the following error : `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]`

I using `virtualhost` for the project.
Using `Xampp with windows`.

Comment: you've got redis set up correctly, andalso check that you're targeting the correct port?

Comment: Yes everything is good ! I think ! If you need something i can update my question !

Comment: Make sure you're running inside Vagrant instead of on your local machine

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First make sure Redis is actually listening on that port by opening up powershell and typing `netstat -aon | more` (this command may need to be enabled in features or installed somehow).  If it is listening then check your firewall settings. If if not listening then make sure Redis is started and is configured to listen on that port.

It looks like `predis/predis` is a client library only.  See https://packagist.org/packages/predis/predis.

You need to install the Redis server, but it looks like it is not officially supported on Windows. See http://redis.io/download.  Per information on that page, it looks like there is a Win64 port for Redis here https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis.

If it still doesn't work after that then update your question with the new error you see.

Comment: Yes there isn't `6379` port listening... What should i do !

Comment: Hmmm, from a quick google search it looks like `predis/predis` is merely a Redis client library.  Did you install the Redis server?  I updated my answer with more info.

Comment: Yes i have redis server and installed.

Comment: Apparently it is not running or not listening on that port..  I would make sure I could reach the redis server directly through by using telnet or a redis client...check out http://fellowtuts.com/php/install-redis-redis-extension-in-php-on-windows/.  Besides that you'll want to post all the relevant configs and command outputs to get any more help on this.  Also note that this issue is getting into systems stuff and may be more suited for the Super User sister site.

Comment: Perfect Man ! Sounds great !

Answer (score 23):

I had this issue in Ubuntu 18.04

I installed redis in my local system, got solved.

```
sudo apt-get install redis-server
```

Comment: This is the kind of simple verification that few talk about. Thanks!

Comment: And run in terminal: `redis-server`

Comment: yeap. worked also with Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 5):

A solution for macbook pro on M1: 
Replace:

```
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

with:

```
REDIS_HOST=host.docker.internal
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been searching for hours!

Answer (score 3):

Ref solution: https://rapidsol.blogspot.com/2018/10/php-fatal-error-uncaught.html

It is showing your server is not accepting connections from outside. You need to provide ip of your redis server.

```
$client = new Predis\Client('tcp://192.168.1.103:6379');
//$client = new Predis\Client();
$client->set('foo', 'bar');
$value = $client->get('foo');
echo $value; exit;
```

if problem still come then try below steps.

So you need to edit :
$sudo vi /usr/local/etc/redis.conf

and find the line  bind 127.0.0.1 ::1
and change it to  #bind 127.0.0.1 ::1
and then find line protected-mode yes
and then change it to protected-mode no

and then restart the redis server

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mac try to install it [here](https://redis.io/docs/getting-started/installation/install-redis-on-mac-os/)

check brew is installed

```
brew --version
```

install redis-server

```
brew install redis
```

run server

```
redis-server
```

Comment: I have Mac book pro M1, and the above one worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Install redis-server depending your MAC machine.

brew install redis

or

```
arch -arm64 brew install redis
```

2. Run server 
   If you want to run it for one time use it

   redis-server

or if you want to run it as background service

```
brew services start redis
```

3. Test it
   This command will open redis environment so you can check on your server side

   redis-cli

You will see environment 127.0.0.1:6379. Just write "ping" and you will get result as "PONG". If you get this result it works.

[Reference for tutorial](https://medium.com/@anarmammadli/how-to-install-redis-on-mac-for-laravel-46c6019dff65)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Redis, make sure that **Redis server is up and running**, by default Redis runs on 6379 port.

If you are on local environment when you restart the machine sometimes you might need to restart Redis server as well.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer so that others can have the full context.

Comment: Added a better description of the context